# React Native Navigation Variable:self issue

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I just finished with *Expo Setup* and my App is running fine on both Android and iOS simulator, but after `npm install react-navigation` which installed for me react navigation 2.14.2, my App crashed with the exception

> unhandled JS Exception:
>   Requiring module 'fetch', which threw an exception:
>   ReferenceError: Can't find Varible:self

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

This is because of the new “whatwg-fetch” 3.0.0 published recently, Just add the following:

**1. You just need to add the previous version of "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.4" in package.json dependency manually.**

**2. Then “yarn add whatwg-fetch@2.0.4.” Or with “npm add whatwg-fetch@2.0.4”.**

**3. npm install**

You are good to go then..